# running geb test with gradle 2.3 - HashMap$Entry exception

Tags: groovy, gradle, geb

I am trying to run geb tests through gradle. I've these installed

java version "1.8.0_31"

Groovy Version: 2.4.0

Gradle 2.3

But i am getting this error when running the test.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/HashMap$Ent
ry
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
```

Running  a simple groovy script with above setup and the below Build.gradle is fine.

Build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }    
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
           def seleniumVersion = "2.45.0"
           def phantomJsVersion = '1.1.0'



    // selenium drivers

    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
    compile("com.github.detro.ghostdriver:phantomjsdriver:$phantomJsVersion") {
    transitive = false
    }
    // geb
    compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2'
    compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.7.2'

     // spock
    compile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.6-groovy-1.8'

    //junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.7'
        }

        task runGebScript (dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
        main = 'test'
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is trying to use the inner class `HashMap.Entry`, which no longer exists in Java 8.  It's difficult to tell where without a complete stack trace.

However, you're using this version of spock: `org.spockframework:spock-core:0.6-groovy-1.8`.  That version is not compatible with groovy 2.0+.  Try updating the dependency to `org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4`.

Comment: Thank youo ! that was the issue. Its runs fine after upgrading spock to `'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'`

Answer (score 1):

According to Gradle dependency report for the build you included, the Groovy version used for `testCompile` configuration is 1.8.5. Only groovy 2.x is JDK8 compatible. I would do as ataylor suggests and bump Spock version. If you use 1.0-groovy-2.4 then you'll be using Groovy 2.4.1. Also, I would suggest updating version of Geb while you're at it - the latest is 0.10.0. Your dependency versions are way out of date.